# Limits, counter-example

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Regarding this question here:

If there exists an $L ∈ R$ such that $\lim_{x→x_0} f(x) = L$ for every $x_0 ∈ R$, then $f (x) = L$ for every $x ∈ R$.

I think this is false, and I am trying to find a counter example for that.

Can someone please give me a hint for how to find the right $f(x)$ that counter this statement?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $f(x)=L$ for $x\notin\Bbb Z$ and $f(n)=L+1$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$..

Comment: Roughly, $f(x) \equiv 0$ except that $f(0) = 1$ should work, I think.

Comment: Thanks, but why lim f(x)=L here?

Comment: If $x_0\ne 0$ we can set $\delta = |x_0|>0$.  So if $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$ then $x\ne 0$ and $f(x)=0$ so $|f(x) - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$ for all positive epsilon.  So that means $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = 0$.  And if $x_0 = 0$ then we can set $\delta$ to anything positive.  If $0 < |x-0| < \delta$ then $x\ne 0$ so $f(x) = 0$ and $|f(x) -0| = 0 < \epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$.  So $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0$.  So for all possible $x_0$ we have $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = 0$.  But $f(0) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true if $f$ is continuous at all $x_0$.

So to find a counterexample we need to consider an $x_0$ there $f$ is not continuous at $x=x_0$ and that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L \ne f(x_0)$.

Now our concern is that if $f(x_0) \ne L$ does that mean there is some $x_1$ "near" so that $\lim_{x\to x_1} f(x)$ can't be $L$ because $f(x_0)\ne L$ knocks it out of whack?

Well, no, $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ and as $x$ "goes to" $x_1$ it will "pass by" $x_0$ and go through infinitely many other $x$s and as $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ the value of $f(x_0)$ doesn't matter in the least.

Our simplest counter example is $f(x) = \begin{cases}L&x\ne x_0\\\text{something that isn't }L&x=x_0\end{cases}$

In that case for and $\epsilon > 0$ then for any positive $\delta$ at all, for all $x$ so that $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$ we have $x\ne x_0$ and $f(x)=L$ so  $|f(x)-L| = 0< \epsilon$ so $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = L$.

And for any $y \ne x_0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ if we let $\delta = |y-x_0|$ then if $0< |y-x| < \delta$ then $x \ne x_0$ and $f(x)=L$ so $|f(x)-L| = 0 < \epsilon$.  So $\lim_{x\to y}f(x) = L$.

So $\lim_{x\to w}f(x)=L$ for every $w \in \mathbb R$ but $f$ is not the function $f(x) = L$ because $f(x_0) \ne L$.

====

For a more specific function consider $f$ so that $f(x) = \begin{cases} 14&\text{if }x= 3.2\\\sqrt 5&\text{if }x \ne 3.2\end{cases}$

Claim 1:  $\lim_{x\to 3.2} f(x) = \sqrt 5$.

Pf: this makes sense because for every $x$ that is near to $3.2$ but not equal to $3.2$ we have $f(x)=\sqrt{5}$.  But to prove it formally:

For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = 517,295,746.7$ .  Then if $0 < |x-3.2| < 517,295,746.7$, we will have $x\ne 3.2$ and so $f(x) = \sqrt 5$.  So $|f(x) -\sqrt 5| = |\sqrt 5-\sqrt 5| = 0 < \epsilon$.  And that is the definition of $\lim_{x\to 3.2} f(x) = \sqrt 5$.

(Note:  There is *utterly* no reason to assume $\lim_{x\to 3.2} f(x) =f(3.2)$ unless $f$ is continuous at $3.2$.  It is completely irrelevant what $f(3.2)$ is in actually calculating what $\lim_{x\to 3.2}f(x)$ is (unless $f$ is continuous at $3.2$.)

Claim 2:  If $M\ne 3.2$ then $\lim_{x\to M}f(x) = \sqrt 5$.

Pf:  This makes sense as for all $x$ that are near $M$ but too close to $M$ to be$3.2$ we have $f(x) = \sqrt 5$.  But more formally.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ if we let $\delta = |M-3.2|$ we will notice if $0 < |M-x| < \delta =|M-3.2|$ then $x\ne 3.2$ so $f(x) =\sqrt 5$.  So $|f(x)-\sqrt 5| = |\sqrt 5 -\sqrt 5|=0< \epsilon$.  And that is the definition fo $\lim_{x\to M}f(x) = \sqrt 5$

So $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \sqrt 5$ for every possible $x_0$.  But $f(x) \ne \sqrt 5$ for every possible $x$.  (Because $f(3.2) = 14$.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that I understand your first part, but why do you say "And for any y≠x0...", what is this y?

Comment: $y$ is any number that we take a limit toward.  The premise is $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = L$ for *all* $x_0$.  I fixed $x_0$ to be a specific point where $f(x_0)\ne L$ but $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\ne L$.  But I have to show that $\lim_{x\to \text{something *other* than }x_0}f(x)=L$ for everything else.  ... well I need a *label* for "$\text{something *other* than} x_0$.  So I called it "$y$" and we had to prove $\lim_{x\to y}f(x) = L$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Something is missing for me to see the whole picture, and I just don't know what it is... :/

Comment: Well if $f(x) = 17$ if $x \ne 3$ and $f(3) =29$.  Do you not see that $\lim_{x\to \pi} f(x) = 17$.  And do you see that $\lim_{x\to \sqrt 2} f(x) = 17$.  And do you not see that if $M\in \mathbb R$ and $M \ne 3$ that $\lim_{x\to M}f(x) = 17$.  And finally, do you see that $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x) = 17$?  So that's it! $\lim_{x\to anything} f(x)=17$ but it is not the case that $f(anything)=17$ as $f(3) =29$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have added another answer, can you please confirm that I did right? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}L& x\notin\Bbb Z\\ L+1& x\in\Bbb Z\end{cases}$$

There are easier exmaples, but this one has the maximum amount of dicontiniities.

---

For fixed $x_0\in\Bbb R$, you can find $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)=L$ for all $0<|x-x_0|<\delta $ (just take, for instance,  $\delta:=\frac{1}{2}{\rm dist}(x_0,\Bbb Z))=\frac{1}{2}\min\{x_0-\lfloor x_0\rfloor, \lceil x_0\rceil -x_0\}$ -where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the floor function and $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ the ceil function).

So For any $\varepsilon>0$, take exactly THIS $\delta$ so if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $x\notin\Bbb Z$ and $f(x)=L$, so  $|f(x)-L|=|L-L|=0<\varepsilon$. And this is the definition of $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$.

Comment: Why is the limit equals to L here?

Comment: All discontinuity points are isolated points: For fixed $x_0\in\Bbb R$, you can find $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)=L$ for all $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ (just take, for instance,  $\delta:=\frac{1}{2}{\rm dist}(x_0,\Bbb Z))$.

Comment: I guess I will have to prove that to use it. I tried to think of functions like 1/x and so..

Comment: See my edited answer @Math4me

Comment: Thank you so much for that my friend! Another question, why is the limit equals to L and not L+1?

Comment: Another edit @Math4me But it is the last one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for your time :)

Comment: "There are easier exmaples"  I highly doubt that!  There are others but this with one discontinuity is as easy as it can get, I think.

Comment: Just one discontinuity is easier than infinitely many.

Comment: "but this one has the maximum amount of discontinuities"  Um... don't you mean *minimum"?

Comment: Can you found a function with that property AND with an uncountable amount of discontinuities? @fleablood I think it doesn't exist, but if not, I would be very interested init.

Comment: I doubt it too. Um... what exactly do you think it is that I am *saying* that you ask me this?  Surely a function with uncountable is *not* easier than a function with only one.  And surely $1$ can't be the *maximal* number of discontinuities if it's possible to have, say, *two* discontinuities.  Or am I mistaken in my belief that there are cardinalities between $1$ and "uncountable"?

Comment: Oh... I misunderstood you function. I thought it was $f(x)=L$ for all but one point.  i.e. $f(x) = L$ if $x \ne c$ and $f(c) = L+1$... So okay.  Um but "There are easier exmaples, but this one has the maximum amount of dicontiniities."  Um, why would a maximum number of discontinuities be a *good* thing in an example?

Comment: Is the worst behaviour possible, I think

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @fleablood.

Let me see If I got it:

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases}L&x\ne b\\L/2 &x=b\end{cases}$

For $lim_{x->b}f(x)=L$

Let $\varepsilon >0$. We choose $δ=\varepsilon$

Let $x \in R$ such that $0<|x-b|<δ$

So $|f(x)-L| = |L-L| = 0 < \varepsilon$

And that's because $0<|x-b|$ so $x\ne b$ and $f(x)=L$.

For $x_{0} \ne b$ , $lim_{x->x_{0}}f(x)=L$

Let $\varepsilon >0$. We choose $δ=|x_{0}-b|$

Let $x \in R$ such that $0<|x-x_{0}|<δ$

So $|x-x_{0}| < |x_{0}-b|$

So $x \ne b$ and so $h(x)=L$

$|h(x)-L| = |L-L| = 0 < \varepsilon $

Is that correct? I think that I missed something here.
Thanks!!